# php $_POST var with same name

Tags: php

i have a form where i have form fields with the same names but different values.

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="D">
<b>A</b> When the router boots up, the Cisco IOS image is loaded from a secured FTP location</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="A">
<b>B</b> The Cisco IOS image file is not visible in the output of the show flash command.</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="C">
<b>C</b> The Cisco IOS image is encrypted and then automatically backed up to the NVRAM.</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="B">
<b>D</b> The Cisco IOS image is encrypted and then automatically backed up to a TFTP server.</p>
```

my idea is to concatenate the values of the checked boxes using the same $_POST variable, but php only save the last value from top down. is there a way to do this or do i have to change 'answer' to 1, 2 ,3 and concatenate them in another variable?

Comment: Use `name="answer[]"` instead.

Comment: thats a good idea, all i have to do is to convert them in strings.

Comment: You should be using radio buttons for this, unless you can have multiple answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set names to answer[] and $_POST['answer'] variable will be an array of selected values. Like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="C">
```

Answer (score 2):

Change answer to 'answer[]'.  This should create an array of items that will carry over in the post content.

Answer (score 1):

Use `name="answer[]"` in **HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<p><input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="D">
    <b>A</b> When the router boots up, the Cisco IOS image is loaded from a secured FTP location</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="A">
    <b>B</b> The Cisco IOS image file is not visible in the output of the show flash command.</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="C">
    <b>C</b> The Cisco IOS image is encrypted and then automatically backed up to the NVRAM.</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="B">
    <b>D</b> The Cisco IOS image is encrypted and then automatically backed up to a TFTP server.</p>
<input type="submit">
```

**In test.php**

```
<?php
print '<pre>';
print_r($_POST['answer']); // $_POST['answer'] returns an array with checked checkbox
print '<pre>';
?>
```